# How to call function every 60 seconds in Polymer 2.x

Tags: polymer-2.x

I wish to call a function in Polymer element every 60 seconds to autosave to persist a result in database (let's assume that DB operations will happen within 60 secs). How can this be achieved in Polymer?

is setTimeout() a good option? how to use it call a function every 60 seconds which is part of polymer element?

```
 setTimeout(async () => {...},6000); // how to make this function called every 60 seconds?
```

I wish to have a polymer 2x function being called every x time interval

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) for that.